# Calculate new hight of a moving object being hit from underneath

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics

I have an old exam-question I have truoble understanding.

A skeet with mass `M = 0.25 kg` is fired away with initial speed 25 m/s and 28 degrees. When the skeet has reached its highest point h, it gets hit by a bullet with mass `m = 0.005 kg` and `v_p = speed 230 m/s` from straight underneath. The bullet penetrates and gets stuck inside the skeet. How much higher will the skeet end up(with the bullet inside).

According to the teacher the answer is(I assume h` is the new height and v_2 the new speed):

"At time of impact: $mv_p = (M + m)v_2  \Rightarrow  v_2 = \frac{m}{M + m}v_p$
Mechanical energy is preserved after the impact. $\Rightarrow (M + m)h`g = \frac{1}{2}(M+m)v_2^{2} \Rightarrow h` = \frac{m^{2}v_p^{2}}{(M+m)^22g} = \frac{230^{2}*0.005^{2}}{0.255^{2}*2*9.81} = 1.037m$"

What I don't understand is how we get from here:
$(M + m)h`g = \frac{1}{2}(M+m)v_2^{2}$
to  here: $h` = \frac{m^{2}v_p^{2}}{(M+m)^22g}$

When I solve for $h`$ I get:
$h` = \frac{v_2^{2}}{2g} $

Any help understanding this is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that this site is not a place to obtain solutions to worked problems. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/25301) and [this Meta post for "check my work problems"](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/25301).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Note that both the answers are the same.

$v_2=\frac{m}{M+m}v_p$.

Put this in $h'=\frac{v_2^2}{2g}$ and get the first expression. Your teacher has just expressed the answer in the variables given in the question.

Comment: Its actually (Change of kinetic energy)+(Change of potential energy)=0. In the above case, when the skeet (with the bullet) stops, the change of kinetic energy is $\frac{1}{2}m(0)^2-\frac{1}{2}(M+m)v_2^2=-\frac{1}{2}(M+m)v_2^2$. And the change of potential energy is $(M+m)gh'$. So $-\frac{1}{2}(M+m)v_2^2+(m+M)gh'=0$, the equation that was used.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: As I said, its not the _potential energy_, but the **change of potential energy**. In the last equation of my previous comment, notice that the first term is the **change of kinetic energy**.  The second term is the **change of potential energy**. If an object at height $h_1$ rises to $h_2$, the **change of potential energy** is $mg(h_2-h_1)$. In the above case, the change of height is $h'$, so **change of potential energy** is $(M+m)gh'$. And since the total energy of the 'earth and skeet(and bullet) system' is fixed, the **total change of energies** is 0. That's what we've done.

Comment: Potential energy by itself makes no sense, unless you assign a reference level. And then, the **potential energy** is actually the **change of potential energy**, from the reference level. As gravitational force is conservative, the total energy of the system is constant, and the total **change of energy** is equal to 0.